# Receiving notification when device registry property changes

Tags: c++, windows, driver

I need to receive current power state of a device. I was able to retrieve it using the code below:

```
ULONG ulRegDataType;
CM_POWER_DATA powerData;
ULONG ulLength;
auto ret = CM_Get_DevNode_Registry_PropertyW(devInst, CM_DRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA, &ulRegDataType, &powerData, &ulLength, 0);
```

I wasn't able, however, to install notification callback with `CM_Register_Notification` that would notify me about the property change. I tried both `CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_FLAG_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES` and `CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_FLAG_ALL_DEVICE_INSTANCES` but the callback is never called when device enters D3 state.

Comment: What do you mean by "I was able to do so using the code below" (i.e. receive), if you could not "install notification callback". How do you know that receiving works if you never got anything sent which could be received?

Comment: @Yunnosch my choice of words is somewhat confusing, apologies for that. What i mean is that i can retrieve the device property using the code i presented but i wasn't able to receive notification when the property changes.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your question to improve clarity.

Comment: @Yunnosch made the changes to make it clear

Comment: I don't think you can use CM_Register_Notification() because it only notifies on device node state change, AFAIK Dx State of the driver does not impact the device node state.